# Defining parametric commands - issue with nested csname

Tags: tex-core, csname

I'm trying to define a parametric command: in particular the code

```
\definecoloredblock{example}{black}{bg=red!50!white,fg=black}{bg=red!30!white,fg=black}
```

should define the commands `\example`, `\@exampleA` and `\@exampleB`. (See the code below)

```
\makeatletter
% definecolorblock <blockname> <titlecolor> <titlebg> <bodybg>
\def\definecoloredblock#1#2#3#4{%
  \expandafter\def\csname @#1A\endcsname[##1]%
  \expandafter{%
    \block{\textcolor{#2}{##1}}%
  }

  \expandafter\def\csname @#1B\endcsname%
  \expandafter{%
    \vspace*{-3ex}%
    \block{\vspace*{-5ex}}%
  }

  \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname%
  {%
    \expandafter\begingroup%
    \expandafter{\setbeamercolor{block title}{#3}}% 
    \expandafter{\setbeamercolor{block body}{#4}}%
    \expandafter\@ifnextchar\expandafter[%
    \csname @#1A\endcsname%
    \csname @#1B\endcsname%
    % ]
  }

  \expandafter\def\csname end#1\endcsname%
  \expandafter{%
    \endblock%
    \endgroup%
  }
}
\makeatother

\definecoloredblock{example}{black}{bg=red!50!white,fg=black}{bg=red!30!white,fg=black}
```

This piece of code doesn't show any errors, but when i try to use it, like:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Frame title}
    \begin{example}[Fake example]
      Some text
    \end{example}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get an error

```
! Use of \@exampleB doesn't match its definition.
\beamer@doifinframe ...me title} \begin {example}[
                                                  Fake example] Some 
text...
l.44 \end{frame}
```

How can i solve my problem?
I guess it is related to the `\csname` after the `\@ifnextchar`.

---

[image: Expected output]

See the answer of egreg for the solution.

Comment: The given `document` code does not show that it uses your nested macros at all. Shall we glue the fragments together?

Comment: it's not entirely clear what the intention of the `\expandafter` is, for example 
  `\expandafter\def\csname @#1B\endcsname\expandafter` if `#1` is `foo` is `\def\@fooB\expandafter` which is a syntax error

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The line `\definecoloredblock{example}{black}{bg=red!50!white,fg=black}{bg=red!30!white,fg=black}` should expand into the definition of `\example`, `\@exampleA`, `\@exampleB` and `\endexample`. In turn `\begin{example}` is just an `\example` (or so I was told) and `\end{example}` executes `\endexample`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I may be wrong, but if #1 is foo I think `\expandafter\def\csname @#1B\endcsname%
  \expandafter{%
    \vspace*{-3ex}%
    \block{\vspace*{-5ex}}%
  }` --> `\def\@fooB%{%\vspace*{-3ex}%\block{\vspace*{-5ex}}%}`.

I'm not sure of that, but an expandafter before a group should delay expansion of the whole group.

Comment: @trenta3 no, it works as I said. `\expandafter{\vspace` expands `\vspace` one step so is the same as `{\protect\vspace_`

Comment: Your question would be a lot clearer if you said in words what you wanted the code to do, and you provided a complete document and described in words what output you want. If you just post not working code it is hard to guess what it was intended to do.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, what I want is to have a command which, given a <name> and some color personalizations, defines an environment to create a block with the given colors in title and body. I will update the question with a complete document (and expected output) soon.

Comment: To explain the error message (“`Use of \@exampleB doesn't match its definition`”): If you write `\def\@exampleB\asdfghjk{Hey this is B}`, then you always need to use it as `\@exampleB\asdfghjk`. What you have basically defined here (`\expandafter\def\csname @#1B\endcsname\expandafter{…`) is something similar, with `\expandafter` in place of `\asdfghjk`, and the fact that `\expandafter` is a TeX primitive doesn't matter: in this context it's just a token.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually I think `\def\@fooB\expandafter` is not a syntax error it is just a very weird thing to do (see error message and previous comment) :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR well yes, true, it defines the command to be a syntax  error as used:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `\expandafter` is mostly wrong. Note that nothing is expanded during a definition.

There are shorthands for `\expandafter\def\csname...\endcsname` and for `\csname...\endcsname` that are easier to use.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% definecolorblock <blockname> <titlecolor> <titlebg> <bodybg>
\def\definecoloredblock#1#2#3#4{%
  \@namedef{@#1A}[##1]{%
    \block{\textcolor{#2}{##1}}%
  }%
  \@namedef{@#1B}{%
    \vspace*{-3ex}%
    \block{\vspace*{-5ex}}%
  }
  \@namedef{#1}{%
    \begingroup
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{#3}%
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{#4}%
    \@ifnextchar[{\@nameuse{@#1A}}{\@nameuse{@#1B}}%]
  }
  \@namedef{end#1}{%
    \endblock
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother

\definecoloredblock{example}{black}{bg=red!50!white,fg=black}{bg=red!30!white,fg=black}

\makeatletter
\show\example
\show\@exampleA
\show\@exampleB
\show\endexample
\makeatother

\stop
```

Here's what's in the console

```
> \example=macro:
->\begingroup \setbeamercolor {block title}{bg=red!50!white,fg=black}\setbeamer
color {block body}{bg=red!30!white,fg=black}\@ifnextchar [{\@nameuse {@exampleA
}}{\@nameuse {@exampleB}}.
l.29 \show\example

? 
> \@exampleA=macro:
[#1]->\block {\textcolor {black}{#1}}.
l.30 \show\@exampleA

? 
> \@exampleB=macro:
->\vspace *{-3ex}\block {\vspace *{-5ex}}.
l.31 \show\@exampleB

? 
> \endexample=macro:
->\endblock \endgroup .
l.32 \show\endexample

? 
 )
No pages of output.
```

However, it's much easier to use `xparse` for the job. Note that I changed the name of the defined environment, because `example` is already defined in `beamer`. Using `\def` exposes to several risks.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\definecoloredblock}{mmmm}{%
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{#1}{o}
    {% start code
     \setbeamercolor{block title}{#3}%
     \setbeamercolor{block body}{#4}%
     \IfNoValueTF{##1}
       {\vspace*{-3ex}\block{\vspace*{-5ex}}}% no optional argument
       {\block{\textcolor{#2}{##1}}}%
    }
    {% end code
     \endblock
    }
}

\definecoloredblock
  {myexample}
  {black}
  {bg=red!50!white,fg=black}
  {bg=red!30!white,fg=black}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

Text

\begin{myexample}
Text in the block
\end{myexample}

Text

\begin{myexample}[Title]
Text in the block
\end{myexample}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is indeed what I was trying to archieve. This code works as intended.

I thought the expandafter would not expand the whole group but I was wrong.

Comment: @trenta3 You probably had `\unexpanded` in mind, but it would be wrong.

Comment: @trenta3 You might enjoy the new version based on `xparse`.

Comment: I do enjoy it, since it looks really clean.

Answer (score 1):

taking a best guess at the intended meaning,

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\def\definecoloredblock#1{%
  \expandafter\@definecoloredblock
      \csname#1\expandafter\endcsname
      \csname end#1\expandafter\endcsname
      \csname @#1A\expandafter\endcsname
      \csname @#1B\endcsname}

\def\@definecoloredblock#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
 \def#3[##1]{%
    \block{\textcolor{#5}{##1}}%
  }%
  \def#4{%
    \vspace*{-3ex}%
    \block{\vspace*{-5ex}}%
  }%
 \def#1{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{#6}% 
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{#7}%
    \@ifnextchar[#3#4%
    %]
  }%
  \def#2{%
    \endblock
  }%
}

\definecoloredblock{example}{black}{bg=red!50!white,fg=black}{bg=red!30!white,fg=black}



\makeatother






  \begin{frame}{Frame title}
    \begin{example}[Fake example]
      Some text
    \end{example}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```